# How to find out time required to travese betwen two webpages?

Tags: java, html, ping

Suppose there is a website consisting of 5 pages.. (Home, About Us, Contact, Gallery, Downloads). Let us assume that there is no navigation bar just individuals pages have links.

Right now "Home" page is open on my window and I need to traverse to "Gallery". How can we measure the time required to reached from home page to Gallery page.(page load time, rendering time are not to be considered)? Can we find the time from the moment i clicked the link till the moment the page recieved the request.

I have tried using `connect()` of `HttpURLConnection.class` (Java)

```
long t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
Connect();
long t2=System.currentTimeMillis();
connection_time=t2-t1;
```

But this code gives the time required to ping the webpage. Can we find time required to ping 'Gallery' from 'Home'.(Specially using java since my application is written in java.)

Comment: The time required to "go" from the home page to another page is the time it takes for you to ping the server with an HTTP request, and receive a response back.  You aren't really going anywhere, in general, other than in between your computer and the web site server.

Comment: have you thougt about the `Timer ` class in Java? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html  Start a timer before the click and end it after page load? or is this not sufficent?

Comment: Ok.. so the logic for measuring time seems apt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Use this to call a javascript function (myFunction), in the function, print current time,  and on next page - also print current time.

NOTE - this will include the time taken by user to click on the link.

EDIT - You can also try with debug option with browser (use FFox / Chrome, hit f12), on network tab - check timelines.

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit the webpage. just I can analyse the exsisting Website.